# VBScript Logic not clear.

Tags: vbscript

So i wanted to get into encryption. So i learned vbscript.  I saw a piece of code that i could read half of it but the other half of it i couldent read.  And no where out there on the internet was there a place where it explained what these lines of code mean.  Can anyone tell me what these lines of code do:

```
function encode(s)
For i = 1 To Len(s)
newtxt = Mid(s, i, 1)
newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt)+5)
coded = coded & newtxt
Next
encode = coded 
End Function
```

HERE IS THE WHOLE PIECE OF CODE:

```
set x = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
mySecret = inputbox("enter text to be encoded") 
mySecret = StrReverse(mySecret)
x.Run "%windir%\notepad"
wscript.sleep 1000
x.sendkeys encode(mySecret)

function encode(s)
For i = 1 To Len(s)
newtxt = Mid(s, i, 1)
newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt)+5)
coded = coded & newtxt
Next
encode = coded 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much encryption as it is obfuscation.

1. Loop through each character in the variable `s`.
2. Grab the next character in the string.
3. Advance the character 5 steps.
4. Append the advanced character to a new string.
5. After looping through the entire string, return the new 'encoded' string.

It takes a character of the alphabet and moves it 5 characters to the right so that 'A' becomes 'F'.

Check this out: [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

Comment: Actually it is encryption (a so-called [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) minus the modulo operation). The algorithm is quite weak, though.

Comment: Touche. I suppose I could have made my point a bit clearer. I like to avoid using words like encryption when it comes to simple algorithms like this so as to avoid the implication of actual security. But yes, you're right.